# The composition of a tricolorable knot with another knot is always tricolorable

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

> Prove that the composition of a tricolorable knot and another knot (except the unknot, whether tricolorable or not) is tricolorable.

I understand that the composition of two tricolorable knots are tricolorable, but I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A tricoloring of a knot diagram requires that the three incident strands at a crossing are either all distinct colors or all the same color (and, depending on your definition, usually at least two or all three colors must be used *somewhere* in the diagram).

Therefore, given a tricolored knot $K$ and any other knot $K'$, we get a nontrivial tricoloring of $K \# K'$ by assigning $K'$ the color of the strand of $K$ onto which it is summed. See the example below.

[image: Tricolorable connected sum]

In fact, it appears that a connected sum of two knots is tricolorable if and *only if*  one of the knots is tricolorable, according to [this write-up](http://www.math.csusb.edu/reu/previouswork/kh10.pdf) of an REU project by Kelly Harlan.